# loading multiple beans in spring boot using soap web service

Tags: soap, spring-boot, wsdl

I  am trying to write soap webservice using spring boot.I have 2 xsd's. REL-6-MM7-1-4.xsd which is dependent on SoapEnvelope.xsd.

Can anyone help me in resolving it.

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition;
import org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidator;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchemaCollection;


@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "REL-6-MM7-1-4")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchemaCollection xsdSchemaCollection) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("MMSPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-6-MM7-1-4");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchemaCollection(xsdSchemaCollection);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchemaCollection getXsdCollection() {
        return new XsdSchemaCollection() {

            public XsdSchema[] getXsdSchemas() {
                return new XsdSchema[]{new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("REL-6-MM7-1-4.xsd")), new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("SoapEnvelope.xsd"))};
            }

            public XmlValidator createValidator() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
    }
```

I have tried to expose 2 beans but when i startup the application i get following error.

Error creating bean with name 'REL-6-MM7-1-4' defined in class path resource [hello/WebServiceConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify your method as below it should work.

```
    @Bean
    public XsdSchema studentSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("school.xsd"));
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema employeeSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("employee.xsd"));
    }     


     @Bean
        public XsdSchemaCollection getXsdCollection() {

        return  new XsdSchemaCollection() {

        @Override
        public XmlValidator createValidator() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public XsdSchema[] getXsdSchemas() {
            return new XsdSchema[]{studentSchema(),employeeSchema()}; 
        }};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
wsdl11Definition.setSchemaCollection(updateXsds());
....
@Bean
public XsdSchemaCollection updateXsds() throws Exception {

    CommonsXsdSchemaCollection xsds = new CommonsXsdSchemaCollection(
        new ClassPathResource("xsd1.xsd"),
        new ClassPathResource("xsd2.xsd")
        );

    xsds.setUriResolver(new DefaultURIResolver());
    xsds.setInline(true);
    return xsds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the spring's tutorial from [their site](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service) then you can use multiple @Bean methods but with the same corespodent names.

> You need to specify bean names for MessageDispatcherServlet and DefaultWsdl11Definition. Bean names determine the URL under which the web service and the generated WSDL file are available.

This way, you can pick witch one you want.
It should look somehting like this

```
@Bean(name = "REL-6-MM7-1-4")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition RELWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema schema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(schema);
    // omitted code... 
}
@Bean(name = "SoapEnvelope")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition SoapEnvelopeWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema schema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    /// omitted code...     
}

@Bean
public XsdSchema REL-6-MM7-1-4Schema() {
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("REL-6-MM7-1-4.xsd"));
}

@Bean
public XsdSchema SoapEnvelopeSchema() {
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("SoapEnvelope.xsd"));
}
```